# jest "Cannot find module" error when importing node module

Tags: angular, testing, npm, jestjs, mocking

I have an angular component that imports

```
import { FileSaverService } from 'ngx-filesaver';
```

When running jest, it throws an "Cannot find module 'ngx-filesaver' from src/.."

Tried to mock ngx-filesaver but still getting that error.

Comment: Did you install the `ngx-filesaver` package and how did you mock this module?

Comment: Yep I installed it.
Throwing that exception although the mocks

Comment: @slideshowp2 do you have a sample of a working mock?

Comment: @NivNavick, could you share a min repo with the error?

Comment: @satanTime, I extracted the important parts to pasteBin https://pastebin.com/4ijn4Pub

Comment: Could you add there also where and how you import its module?

Comment: On Monday I’ll be at my laptop to check. I think jest.mock isn’t correct. Could you try instead or it that way? https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockProvider